# how to centre image over html table

Tags: html

I want to show image over html table and in centre. How to achieve this? 
This image is nothing but a progress bar. So this image will appear over html table while it is loading. I tried like this below but it is not coming over html table and in center of table.

```
<div style="overflow: auto;height: 400px">
    <table id ="tbl"  style="width: 100%;background-image: url(img/busyIndicator.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center" >
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 30px"/>
            <col style="width: 10px"/>
            <col style="width: 1px" />
            <col style="width: 80px"/>
            <col/>
        </colgroup>
        <script id="Template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <tr >
            <td>${Id}</td>
            <td>${Age}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>${Name}</td>
        </tr>
        </script>

        <tbody id="List">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Hope it clarifies my question. Let me know if you need more info.

**Update1**

I have now added image on table instead of td but still not showing up

**Update2**
I am loading data into my jquery template via ajax call. Not sure if  need to show my code for ajax call. So image should appear when data is loading and it should go off when its finished loading

Comment: you need the progress bar to appear on top of your table while the table is loading and to vanish after the loading is completed right? You may need to use javascript for that.
And are you saying that the image is not at all loading or that it is loading only at the center of the table?

Comment: put the image in a div and float it over the top of the table

Comment: @HarikrishnanT you are quite right. How to do this?

Comment: @Prospector can you tell me how?

Answer (score 2):

In the style property, just add:

```
background-position: center center;
```

So it beacame:

```
<td style="background-image: url(img/img1.gif); background-position: center center" ></td>
```

Read more here -> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Ps: In style attribute is better if you are synthetic, so you can write all in this way

```
background: url(img/img1.gif) center center;
```

Look here to learn how the "background" property work -> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

EDIT:

If you wantto put the loading img in a  tag and position it in center of the td, you have to assign to the image this style:

```
style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle; margin:auto"
```

But, please, give a class on that image and write the style in a css file.

Comment: So you put it on a image, in this way you have to delete it when the load is ready, I wrote in the comment the right style for the img tag.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to add :

- `position: relative` to the table
- `background-position: center center; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;` to your td

So your code will be :

```
<div style="overflow: auto;height: 400px">
    <table id ="tbl" style="position: relative; width: 100%;" >
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 30px"/>
            <col style="width: 10px"/>
            <col style="width: 1px" />
            <col style="width: 80px"/>
            <col/>
        </colgroup>
        <script id="Template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <tr >
            <td>${Id}</td>
            <td>${Age}</td>
            <td style="background-image: url(img/img1.gif); background-position: center center; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;"></td>
            <td>${Name}</td>
        </tr>
        </script>

        <tbody id="List">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: its not loading image at all. I am loading data via wcf service into jquery template. So i want my image to be loaded when data is loading and image should go off when its finished

Comment: If not load image at all, it's because links are broken. So you have to set the good links. And, then, if you want your image is loaded when data is loading and image should go off when its finished, you have to use javascript or jquery. You can't do that with HTML only.

Comment: Ok. Send your page. I will try to do it.

Comment: Also the links are not broken. The image path is correct 100%.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33682/discussion-between-happy-and-lucas-willems)